# Caching TemplateView

Tags: python, django, caching

I want to use cache from django to cache one template that makes expensive queries.
I am not sure if I can just use `render()` in the `get` handler as in snippet below:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "my-template.html"
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cached = cache.get("my-view-response")
        if cached:
            return cached
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs).render()  # <---
        cache.set("my-view-response", response)
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...  # expensive queries
        return context
```

Normally `TemplateView.get` returns `TemplateResponse` instance so by calling `render` it feels like I am skipping some steps.
So my question is: is it ok to return string from `TemplateView.get`?

inb4: The webpage loads correctly; I can't cache the `TemplateResponse` instance itself because it throws an exception; I have to use "low-level" cache API cause I am invalidating it when rows are added/deleted or modified (which will not happen often)

Comment: Does the per-view cache not work? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache

Comment: Hm, I guess it doesn't, that's why I wrote the last sentence in my question, but I might be missing something. Is it possible to invalidate/delete the cached response by hand when using per-view cache?

Comment: Can you give an example of when/why you would invalidate the cache?

Comment: For example when user adds a new entry I want it to be immediately visible in the web page.